# javascript regex support for UTF8 characters with Number and letters

Tags: javascript, utf-8, xregexp

How to generate regex for supporting utf8 characters with Numbers [0-9], letters [a-z] and [A-Z].

I am using xregexp library to support utf-8 characters.

Till now i used :

1. XRegExp("^\p{L}\d{0-9}+$") //Not supporting any of them.
2. XRegExp("[^\p{N}\p{L}]") //Not supporting any of them.
3. XRegExp("^\p{L}+$") // Supports only UTF-8 characters, [a-z] and
   [A-Z] and not [0-9]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `\\p{L}+` in combination with `[0-9]`:

```
XRegExp("^(\\p{L}|[0-9])+$")
```

Note that you need to escape your backslash, there: `\\`.

To include `_/-`:

```
XRegExp("^(\\p{L}|[0-9_/-])+$")
```

Note that the dash (`-`) has to be the first or last character in those brackets, due to it's special meaning.

Comment: I also want to add _,/,- characters i.e underscore, forward slash and hyphen characters .

Comment: @vermaraj: I added some more to my answer.

Comment: It worked well. Thanks for the help. I also want to understand what happen if i put dash(-) in between.